# can not get the nth result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need help getting the nth number of a result in MySQL.

I have three tables with the following fields:

```
table1: product_id, name, description

table2: category_id, name, description

table3: product_id, category_id
```

I'm trying to get this result:

```
    name  |   description   -  product_category -category2 - category3
   ___________________________________________________________________
   NAME 1 |  Description 1  |       Cat1        |  Cat2    |   Cat5
   NAME 2 |  Description 2  |       Cat7        |  Cat9    |   Cat11
```

The query I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
SELECT 
t1.name AS product_name,
t1.description AS product_description,
(SELECT t2.name from table2 order by name ASC LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1) AS product_category,

(SELECT t2.name from table2 order by name ASC LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 2) AS product_category2, 

(SELECT t2.name from table2 order by name ASC LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 3) AS product_category3 

FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
table3 t3
ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id INNER JOIN
table2 t2
ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
;
```

And sadly I get this result:

```
name  -   description   -  category

NAME 1 -  Description 1 -  Category 1


NAME 2  - Description 2 -   Category 2
```

Comment: You don't really indicate why that result isn't what you expect.

Comment: You don't have any top level `ORDER BY` clause, so the concept of `nth` is whatever MySQL wants it to be.

Comment: The thing is there should be more categories as mentioned in the description but only one is returned, so basically MYSQL gets the first result then stops looking for more.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer if you look at the question and read all the explanation you will find what im looking for

Comment: Looking to your result you want something like a pivot... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Example:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2
```

Comment: can you **edit** your answer and explain *why* left join could be more appropriate?

Comment: I used that along with some small changes and its sorted. Thanks :D